# What is the difference between DFPBannerView and GADBannerView?

Tags: ios, admob, google-ad-manager

Google ad mob documentation tells me to use a GADBannerView to display ads where as google ad manager tells me to use a DFPBannerView. Both perform exactly the same from what I can tell so why the 2 option?

[Google Ad Mob](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/banner)

[Google Ad Manager](https://developers.google.com/ad-manager/mobile-ads-sdk/ios/banner)

Answer (score 2):

The GMA SDK is shared by both AdMob and Ad Manager, which are two different ad serving solutions. Even if the SDK is the same, you still need to indicate whether the ad serving will be managed by AdMob or Ad Manager. Depending on where you have you're campaigns set up, you'll need to use the appropriate method to request such ads.